# Remove the minimize button on Openbox

Tags: openbox, window-decorations

I am using the Openbox window manager.

I would like to remove the minimize button.

How should I change `rc.xml`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the line reading:

```
  <titleLayout>IMC</titleLayout>
```

and remove the `I`.

Reference: [Openbox Wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration)

Comment: Thank you very much.!!!!!!!!!!!!! openbox is 're able to do everything rc.xml.!!!!! I really really appreciate it !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!